# How can I include data specific to a user in Parse push notifications?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

This is how I'm using Parse JS Cloud Code to send push notifications to the "highPush" subset of users:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("sendHighPush", function(request, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

   Parse.Push.send({
     channels: ["highPush"],
     data: {
     alert: "New match found!",
     badge: "Increment"
     }
   }, 
   {
     success: function() {
        // Push was successful
        console.log('Push Notifications completed successfully.');
     },
     error: function(error) {
      throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
     }
   }).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("Push Notifications completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Uh oh, ain't no pushing going on here.");
  });

});
```

What I want to do is not only send this push notification to all "**highPush**" users, but for the push notification string to include info specific to each user respectively. So rather than the alert saying "New match found!", I want it to say "**New match found for iPhone 5S 16gb!**", where "**iPhone 5S 16gb**" is a string property of an object associated with that specific user.

From what I can see in the Parse documentation, I can only find ways to send a standard push notification to a subset of users, but no way to customize the push notification content to each user individually. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no.. The push data / alert is not customizable for each target in the push query.

At this time you would need to send individual push notifications to those users and include the specific information.